# How to use the word adjustable here?

Tags: prepositions

How can I say this:
These are adjustable (in/for/as far as/through) their angle and height.

Which alternative in parenthesis is correct? Or do you have other better suggestions on how to say this sentence?

Comment: Both the angle and height are adjustable.

Comment: *. . . adjustable in . . .*

Comment: Are there two elements that are independently adjustable in angle and height, or is the angle created *between* the two elements?

Comment: They are independent of each other

Comment: In that case, use @Xanne’s suggestion: it is shorter, uses more natural English, and is less ambiguous.

Answer (score 1):

Unquestionably the best, simplest, most understandable way to write this is:

> Their angle and height are adjustable.

Everything else is more complex and harder to understand. Unless you belong to the school of writing which says that longer, complex and harder to understand is better, then write the sentence above.

If you absolutely insist on writing a more complex sentence, then the least worst options are probably "in" or "in terms of".

Answer (score -1):

"In" seems good enough, but is not ideal.

- These are adjustable in their angle and height.
- The angle and the height of those are adjustable.

"As far as" is perfect if you imply a restriction, but I believe this is not the full locution.

- These are adjustable *as far as* their angle and height *go/are concerned*. (However, there is no way to vary the width.)
- "For" and "Through"  are not a possibility.

There is also the preposition "as to".

([ref.](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/An_Account_of_the_Discoveries_Concerning/SZiBdGoERu8C?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22as+to+angle%22&pg=PA22&printsec=frontcover)) From the table of elements , N : 1 mark true , both as to angle and distance , the perihelion of the comet required : through the sun draw the axis of the ...

([ref.](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Official_Gazette_of_the_United_States_Pa/XWYbAQAAMAAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22as+to+angle%22&pg=PA2817&printsec=frontcover)) ... both as to angle and as to length increase and decrease 6 as said right angle translation mechanism moves , and thereby machine said bore surface

([ref.](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/House_Documents_Otherwise_Publ_as_Execut/AJUFAAAAQAAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22as+to+angle%22&pg=PA669&printsec=frontcover))  The leather is stretched upon the table, which is capable of a partial rotary and also a transverse motion in a horizontal plane beneath the reciprocating tools, which are adjustable as to angle and pressure

([ref.](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Iron_Trade_Review/OBtKAQAAMAAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&bsq=%22as+to+angle%22&dq=%22as+to+angle%22&printsec=frontcover)) this vary as to angle of clearance , angle Bauxite Increases manner , from 12 to 16 settings could of rake